# Execute logic when RxJS 5 refCount() connects to or unsubscribes from source

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

According to the RxJS 5 manual's section on [Multicasting](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#multicasted-observables)

> ...we can use ConnectableObservable's refCount() method (reference counting), which returns an Observable that keeps track of how many subscribers it has. When the number of subscribers increases from 0 to 1, it will call connect() for us, which starts the shared execution. Only when the number of subscribers decreases from 1 to 0 will it be fully unsubscribed, stopping further execution.

I'd like to understand whether it's possible to hook into each of these events and execute some logic, ideally before the source observable's `connect()` or `unsubscribe()` occurs, but even after the fact would be acceptable.

If there's no way to do this when using the `refCount()` operator, it'd be much appreciated if you could provide an example how one could achieve this with a custom operator.

I thought maybe I could somehow use the completeFn from `do(nextFn,errFn,completeFn)` to hook into this, but doesn't seem to work as shown by the below snippet.

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .do(
    (x) => console.log('SOURCE emitted ' + x),
    (err) => console.log('SOURCE erred ' + err),
    () => console.log('SOURCE completed ')
  );
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
var refCounted = source.multicast(subject).refCount();
var subscription1, subscription2, subscriptionConnect;

// This calls `connect()`, because
// it is the first subscriber to `refCounted`
console.log('observerA subscribed');
subscription1 = refCounted.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('observerB subscribed');
  subscription2 = refCounted.subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log('observerB: ' + v)
  });
}, 600);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('observerA unsubscribed');
  subscription1.unsubscribe();
}, 1200);

// This is when the shared Observable execution will stop, because
// `refCounted` would have no more subscribers after this
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('observerB unsubscribed');
  subscription2.unsubscribe();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: What output do you expect from the example you made? I'd think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.do(null,null, onComplete)` before your actual stream and `.finally()` after completion/unsubscribe to have events before subscription and after completion/unsubscribe:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.empty()
  .do(null,null, () => console.log('subscribed'))
  .concat(Rx.Observable.interval(500))
  .finally(() => console.log('unsubscribed'))
  .publish().refCount();

const sub1 = source
  .take(5)
   .subscribe(
     val => console.log('sub1 ' + val),
     null, 
     () => console.log('sub1 completed')
   );
const sub2 = source
  .take(3)
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log('sub2 ' + val), 
    null, 
    () => console.log('sub2 completed')
  );

// simulate late subscription setting refCount() from 0 to 1 again                      
setTimeout(() => {
  source
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(
      val => console.log('late sub3 val: ' + val),
      null, 
      () => console.log('sub3 completed')
    );
 
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
```